# I have a Carrier HVAC unit that came with a washable filter. Can I replace that filter with a disposable one and if so is there and specific type?

Tags: hvac, replacement, filter

I have a Carrier model FB4CNP036 HVAC unit.  I would like to replace the washable filter it came with, with a disposable filter.  Is that possible and if so other than matching the size is there a specific type of filter I would need to purchase?

Comment: Possible, but the cost of buying new filters plus disposing of them, makes a washable one sound good.

Comment: Ideally it should have the same or similar porosity as the older one.

Comment: @crip659 washable is good, but you need two, unless you only wash the filter during late spring or early fall.